# Extract alphanumeric words starting with letter, ignore others

Tags: javascript, regex

Sounds easy enough, but I am just unable to figure that out.

```
/([a-z][a-z0-9]+)/gi
```

Test case looks like this

```
Correct #123    2baZ   #1a2 thisToo  $bar  andTwo2
```

I am fighting with those partial matches. Only valid should be: `["Correct", "thisToo", "andTwo2"]`. Any others should stay unmatched.

Here is link to tester: http://regex101.com/r/qG7lU9/8

**Update**:

Here is JS fiddle that works better than tester itself... http://jsfiddle.net/FredyCr/6hsgef82/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead and non-capturing group based regex like this:

```
(?:^| )([a-z][a-z0-9]+(?= |$))
```

And use captured group #1 for your matches that gives:

```
Correct
thisToo
andTwo2
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG7lU9/13)

**Code:**

```
var rx = /(?:^| )([a-z][a-z0-9]+(?= |$))/gi
var str = "    Correct #123 2baZ   #1a2 thisToo  $bar  andTwo2";

var matches = [];
while (match = rx.exec(str))
    matches.push(match[1]);

console.log(matches);
//=> ["Correct", "thisToo", "andTwo2"]
```

#### [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59tb8txe/2/)

Comment: Pretty much same solution as from @Avinash, not really working well in Javascript.

Comment: Did you check `MATCH INFORMATION` section in the demo? Isn't it what you expected?

Comment: Yes, it looks confusing in that tester, but if you run it through javascript, it's not working... http://jsfiddle.net/59tb8txe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched strings from group index 2.

```
(?:^| )([a-z][a-z0-9]+)(?: |$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qG7lU9/12)

Javascript code would be,

```
> var re = /(?:^| )([a-z][a-z0-9]+)(?: |$)/gi
undefined
> var str = "    Correct #123 2baZ   #1a2 thisToo  $bar  andTwo2";
undefined
> var matches = [];
undefined
> while (match = re.exec(str))
... {
... matches.push(match[1]);
... }
3
> console.log(matches);
[ 'Correct', 'thisToo', 'andTwo2' ]
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, but it's not right yet. Still matches to `$bar` ... http://regex101.com/r/qG7lU9/9

Comment: Well that last edit looks kinda gross, I would like to have a clean array of matched words, not to deal with extra indexes... http://regex101.com/r/qG7lU9/11

Comment: Now I see that in Javascript I cannot even work with indexes when `g` modifier is used. It spits just those words with whitespace characters. I would have to trim it and that's not really effective.

Comment: try `(?:^| )([a-z][a-z0-9]+)(?: |$)`, now have a single capturing group.

Comment: Thanks for effort, but unfortunately this doesn't work well in Javascript... http://jsfiddle.net/59tb8txe/ Resulting array still has those spaces around.

Comment: Awesome, that's it. I was already thinking about something like that. Thank you. Just update your answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: My apologies mate, didn't mean to update your answer.

Comment: @anubhava it's ok. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /(^|\s)[a-z][a-z0-9]+/gi;
var text = "Correct #123    2baZ   #1a2 thisToo  $bar  andTwo2";
var found;
while ((found = regex.exec(text)) !== null)
   console.log(found[0].trim());
```

Output

```
Correct
thisToo
andTwo2
```

Comment: This is similar as two previous answers two. I don't like the idea of using `trim` in there. Isn't there a way to capture it without those spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: split and filter the tokens you want:

```
var rx = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
var match = str.split(/\s+/).filter(rx.exec.bind(rx));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6hsgef82/1/)